# nested Filter json Using Checkboxes with AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, json, checkbox, filter

I had a Json data I need to create a nested  filter search in angular. If you guys can help me since I am new to this I tried but I find difficulty.

Comment: you should make a fiddle

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I dont have your css but at high level it should be like [**THIS**](http://jsfiddle.net/ka2Lt652/1/) and for **multilevel** filter refer **[THIS](http://jsfiddle.net/ka2Lt652/2/)**

On click of checkbox i am adding filter category to one of my array using **addToFilter** function.

**HTML**

```
<input  type="checkbox" ng-checked="item.checked" ng-model="item.checked" ng-click="addToFilter(item.node.category)"/> {{ item.node.category }}
```

**HTML**

code **filter:categoryFilter** will filter records from array according to selected category.

```
<div ng-repeat="item in nodes | filter:categoryFilter | orderBy:'node.location' | groupBy:['node.location'] ">
    <h2 ng-show="item.group_by_CHANGED">{{item.node.location}}</h2>
        <ul>
            <li>{{item.node.title}}</li>
         </ul></div>
```

**JS**

This js code is to add selected category from array when checked and remove when unchecked.

```
$scope.filtersApplied =[];
$scope.addToFilter = function(category)
{
  var i = $.inArray(category.trim(), $scope.filtersApplied);
  console.log(category);
  if (i > -1) {
     $scope.filtersApplied.splice(i, 1);
   } else {
     $scope.filtersApplied.push(category.trim());
   }
}
$scope.categoryFilter = function(node) {
   if ($scope.filtersApplied.length > 0) {
     if ($.inArray(node.node.category.trim(), $scope.filtersApplied) < 0)
     return;
   }
 return node;
}
```

** Please ignore my grouping code. I just want to simulate what you shown in image.

Updated [**SAMPLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/ykfnn2rg/3/) with CSS

Comment: Hello,
you gave exact way what I need but you just copying the Json data but I need  to call it every time since it is dynamic data and it will be change every tim. Coming to the color part is there any way I can generate random classes to the locations names since I need to assign different colors to the different location. Please let me know. Thanks a ton for your help.

Comment: Angular supports two way binding so when you change your variable with new data all filter and grouping will get updated automatically for you. For COLOR CSS you can create your custom class and apply based on index. To achieve that, you need to group first and identify headers and keep track of indexes. Based on index you can apply CSS and it will remain fix at the time of filtering. I have updated sample for you. There are many ways you can achieve it.

Comment: The way you provided worked very good way. I had only one question is there any way can we arrange the alphabetically arrange according the store names in every location right now store titles are showing in scrambled way.@user3249448. Thanks for your efforts.

Comment: Yes its possible. Just let your $scope.groupedData sorting on node.title as well. Updated http://jsfiddle.net/1yh4pwL1/1/

Comment: Hello
Few months back you gave me correct solution for my problem which solves my primary search filter issues which is in this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/1yh4pwL1/1/ but the problem I got here is there is one more filter added which is called subcategory which is having multiple values for every store. I tried it but I am getting duplicate values since the subcategories have multiple values. So please can you check it once and provide some solution please. Here is the JSON URL: http://dev.flydulles.com/store-directory?section=iad. We are in testing so we didnt add subcategories to all stores

Comment: Okay I will try for that.

Comment: I did hack for your requirement. I have added removeDuplicate function after filter and while adding headers title appended with space. This is final updated sample http://jsfiddle.net/9paLz20w/6/   . I hope this solution will resolve your problem. I didnt test all condition :)